# Randomizer doesn't run when I import a module

Tags: python

I use the np.random.rand() function to create a random starting position in a module called 'initialze.py'. Then I import this module in another script, but when I run the other script it doesn't run the randomizing function again. I read that when you import a module it runs the full module, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I would like to be able to only run the other script, let's call it 'launcher.py' and still have 'initialze.py' run it's randomizer function instead of keeping the same values.

Comment: initialize.yourfunctionname() call it inthis way

Comment: `import` runs the code in the file only on the first import, other `import` don't run anything again. You should write code in functions and call them whenever you want from other modules

Answer (score 0):

If you do pure python, import doesn't run the module, it's just allow you to call function declared in module.

To use it in launcher.py just call it like this.

```
initialize.randomFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I set up a structure like so:

```
/:
 - initializer.py 
 - launcher.py
```

where `launcher.py` includes:

```py
import initializer
```

and `initializer.py` includes:

```py
import numpy as np
print(f"Random number is: {np.random.rand()}")
```

then running the two scripts returns the following:

```
(base) $ python3 initializer.py 
Random number is: 0.41155874159797934
(base) $ python3 launcher.py 
Random number is: 0.771030740902452
```

Numpy always generates a different number regardless if you run the `initializer.py` or the `launcher.py` script. So I'm unsure what the problem is. Importing the `initializer.py` script still triggers the RNG operations and the numbers are different each time.

Comment: This is how i set it up aswell, but I would not get a new random number each time. It would simply keep the same randomly generated number that it got the first time. The person above seems to be right, since I am doing it in purely python (spyder).